# My code works differently when its wrapped in a function

Tags: python

I am new into scripting in blender. Currently I am testing code snippets by running them into the python console.
Currently I am facing an issue for a while that I am not able to fix.

I have this code snippet, in which Basically I add a new axis and use it to animate some stuff.
I I run this code snippet everything seems to work fine:

```py
tf = 200
bpy.context.scene.frame_end = tf
i = 0
scene = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"]
axi = bpy.data.objects[f'empty{i:03}']
axx_i = bpy.data.objects.new(f'emptyx{i:03}', None)
axx_i.empty_display_type = 'PLAIN_AXES'
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(axx_i)
x_location, y_location, z_location = get_location()
axx_i.location = (x_location,y_location,z_location)
k = np.random.choice([1,2,3])
#
axx_i = bpy.data.objects[f'emptyx{i:03}']
axx_i.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
#
scene.frame_current = 1
axx_i.rotation_euler = (0, 0, 0)
# THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
axx_i = bpy.data.objects[f'emptyx{i:03}']
axi = bpy.data.objects[f'empty{i:03}']
axi.parent = axx_i
axi.matrix_parent_inverse = axx_i.matrix_world.inverted()
```

however if I wrap the code in a function it works differently. In this case I think that something related to matrix_parent_inverse is not working correctly.

For example if I run the same code but wrapped in a function.

```py
tf = 200
bpy.context.scene.frame_end = tf

def func(i):
    scene = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"]
    # <...>
    # ALL THE CODE FROM ABOVE
    # <...>
    axi.parent = axx_i
    axi.matrix_parent_inverse = axx_i.matrix_world.inverted()

func(i)
```

the parenting seems to be not working.
How can I get the same results when wrap the code in a function.

As I said, both snippets have been run in the python console.

Blender Version 2.93.3 (2.93.3 2021-08-18)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while, but just after the `axi.parent = axx_i`  operation I needed to add this line to fix it

```py
    axi.parent = axx_i
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()
    axi.matrix_parent_inverse = axx_i.matrix_world.inverted()
```